# Integral involving matrix exponential

Tags: integration, matrices, symmetric-matrices, matrix-exponential

Is there any way to simplify the integral 
$$
I = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}e^{\Lambda t} A e^{\Lambda t}\,dt
$$
knowing that A is symmetric and Λ is a diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n$ denote the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$, and let $a_{ij}$ denote the entries of $A$. Note that we have
$$
[e^{\Lambda t}A e^{\Lambda t}](i,j) = e^{(\lambda_i + \lambda_j)t} a_{ij}
$$
Thus, integrating entrywise yields
$$
I(i,j) = \frac{e^{(\lambda_i + \lambda_j)t_2} - e^{(\lambda_i + \lambda_j)t_1}}{\lambda_i + \lambda_j}
$$
in the case that $\lambda_i \neq -\lambda_j$.  If $\lambda_i = -\lambda_j$, then we end up with $I(i,j) = a_{ij}(t_2 - t_1)$.

Comment: +1 for catching the division by zero. Woops.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\Lambda\equiv\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{n})$ and $A\equiv(a_{ij})$.
Then,
$$
[e^{\Lambda t}Ae^{\Lambda t}]_{ij}=e^{(\lambda_{i}+\lambda_{j})t}a_{ij}
$$
and hence
$$
[I]_{ij}=a_{ij}\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}e^{(\lambda_{i}+\lambda_{j})t}dt=a_{ij}\frac{e^{(\lambda_{i}+\lambda_{j})t_{2}}-e^{(\lambda_{i}+\lambda_{j})t_{1}}}{\lambda_{i}+\lambda_{j}}.
$$

BTW, it seems like a dangerous idea to use the symbol $I$ to mean anything other than identity if there are matrices involved.

Comment: Omnomnomnom's answer also works when $\lambda_i + \lambda_j = 0$.